# Using the response of a POST-request in Power Apps

Tags: rest, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps

I'm pretty new to Power Apps, so bear with me on this.
I'm connecting my Power App to a Microsoft Dynamics 365 using a custom connector. So far all good, and I can get data from Dynamics, and make a POST to change data. However, my method that handles the POST in Dynamics returns a boolean to indicate if the action was succesful or not.
My problem is that I have no clue how to handle the response with the boolean.

The picture below is of the response window where I defined what is expected to be returned. I need the "value".
[Response from the POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBQig.png)

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Hi Skollop. Inside Powerapps how are you trying to get the response?